# How to reshape dataframe to turn Columns into Rows using R?

Tags: r

Sorry in case the title is unclear I'm not 100% how to phrase my problem.
I have a Dataframe that looks something like this:

| date | Location A Variable 1 | Location A Variable 2 | Location B Variable 1 | Location B Variable 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 20 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Feb 20 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| ... | ... | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Dec 20 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

and I would like it to look like this:

| date | Location | Variable 1 | Variable 2 | Variable... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 20 | A | 2 | 2 | . |
| Jan 20 | B | 2 | 2 | . |
| Feb 20 | A | 2 | 2 | . |
| Feb 20 | B | 2 | 2 | . |
| ... | ... | 2 | 2 | . |
| Dec 20 | A | 2 | 2 | . |
| Dec 20 | B | 2 | 2 | . |

Comment: You you provide data using `dput(your_data)`?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, welcome to SO! check out ?dplyr::pivot_longer()

Comment: @akrun Yes I do.

Answer (score 3):

If we have spaces in the column name

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df1, cols = -date, names_to = c("Location", ".value"), 
     names_pattern = "\\w+\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(.*)")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  date   Location `Variable 1` `Variable 2`
  <chr>  <chr>           <int>        <int>
1 Jan 20 A                   2            2
2 Jan 20 B                   2            2
3 Feb 20 A                   2            2
4 Feb 20 B                   2            2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("Jan 20", "Feb 20"), `Location A Variable 1` = c(2L, 
2L), `Location A Variable 2` = c(2L, 2L), `Location B Variable 1` = c(2L, 
2L), `Location B Variable 2` = c(2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way could be first with renaming:

```
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr) 
library(stringr) 

df1  %>% 
  rename_with(., ~str_replace_all(., 'Variable', '_Variable')) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -date,
    names_to = c("Location", ".value"), 
    names_sep = '_') %>% 
  mutate(Location = str_squish(str_remove(Location, "Location")))
```

```
 date   Location `Variable 1` `Variable 2`
  <chr>  <chr>           <int>        <int>
1 Jan 20 A                   2            2
2 Jan 20 B                   2            2
3 Feb 20 A                   2            2
4 Feb 20 B                   2            2
```